# Field Initializer Cannot Reference Non-Static Field: Attempting to create Constructor to fix issue

Tags: c#, constructor

I have created a class that generates a Random State. This works. Next, using code samples I found online, I am attempting use Dictionary methods that (1) match a valid city that corresponds with the randomly selected state and (2) match a valid zip code that corresponds with the same randomly selected state.

Here is a sample of the code so far

```
  public class GenerateCityStateZip
    {
        public static string state;
        public static string city;
        public static string zip;
        public static Random rnd = new Random();

        public static string GenRandomState()
        {
            List<string> lst = new List<string>();
            state = string.Empty;
            lst.Add("Alabama");
            lst.Add("Alaska");
            lst.Add("Arizona");
            ...
            state = lst.OrderBy(xx => rnd.Next()).First();
            return state;
        } // End GenRandomState

       public static Dictionary<string, string> cities = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"Alabama", "Huntsville"},
            {"Alaska", "Anchorage"},
            {"Arizona", "Phoenix"},
...
};

       public static string GetCity(string city)
        {
            // Try to get the result in the static Dictionary
            string result;
            if (cities.TryGetValue(city, out result))
            {
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        } // End GetCity

        public static Dictionary<string, string> zipcodes = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"Alabama", "35801"},
            {"Alaska", "99501"},
            {"Arizona", "85001"},
...
};

        public static string GetZip(string zip)
        {
            // Try to get the result in the static Dictionary
            string result;
            if (zipcodes.TryGetValue(zip, out result))
            {
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        } // End GetZip
}
```

I next have a class that is calling the GenerateCityStateZip class for the state city and zip variables. The state variable is generated successfully but I get a message saying "Field Initializer Cannot Reference Non-Static Field" when I attempt to create the city and zip.

I know I need to create a constructor in this class but I am not sure how to correctly implement. Code Below.

```
   // My attempt to create a constructor
    GenerateCityStateZip g = new GenerateCityStateZip();

    string state = GenerateCityStateZip.GenRandomState();


    string city = GenerateCityStateZip.GetCity(state);
    string zip = GenerateCityStateZip.GetZip(state);
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Except for the dictionary initialization, your code example has no field initializers, nor non-static members. It's not clear at all how you could get the error you describe from the code you posted. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. Explain precisely what that code does and how that's different from what you want it to do.

Comment: Make it a public static class. Lose the constructor.

Comment: Thanks Darren - I created a public static class to call the methods. However, I am not sure how I can retrieve the city and zip variables.        public static string getState()
        {
            string state = GenerateCityStateZip.GenRandomState();
            string city = GenerateCityStateZip.GetCity(state);
            string zip = GenerateCityStateZip.GetZip(state);
            return state;
        }

Comment: Your code works fine without the constructor I do not see an issue with that.  Although you are adding essentially the same data three times and should be cleaned up.  A data entry error would cause some headaches.

Answer (score 0):

Using Darren's suggestion, I created public static methods that call the GenerateCityStateZip Class.

```
public static string getState()
        {
            string state = GenerateCityStateZip.GenRandomState();
            return state;
        }
        public string _state = getState();
  public static string getCity(string state)
    {
        string city = GenerateCityStateZip.GetCity(state);
        return city;
    }

    public static string getZip(string state)
    {
        string zip = GenerateCityStateZip.GetZip(state);
        return zip;
    }
```

I next called the methods from another method from inside the secondary class (not the GenerateCityStateZip Class)

```
public void InputNameZipClickNext()
{
    txtClientName.Click();
    txtClientName.SendKeys(bogusCompanyName);
    txtZipCode.Click();
    txtZipCode.SendKeys(getZip(_state));
    txtInsuredName.Clear();
    txtInsuredName.SendKeys(clientCompanyName);
    txtAddressPhysical.Clear();
    txtAddressPhysical.SendKeys(clientAddress);
    txtCityPhysical.Clear();
    txtCityPhysical.SendKeys(getCity(_state));
    txtStatePhysical.SendKeys(_state);
    btnCopyPhysical.Click();
    btnCreateNext.Click();
}
```

Thanks again, Darren